# Popover JS throw error even already include

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, popover

I'm trying to use popover on my local project. I've already included these :

- bootstrap.css v4.2.1
- jquery.min.js v2.2.0
- bootstrap.min.js v4.2.1
- popper.min.js v1.11.0

I had a simple button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

and this JS

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
```

I kept getting

[image]

Did I forgot to do anything else ?

Is the version, I listed above is contradict each other ?

Comment: Have you included the libraries in that specific order?

Comment: Put popper first over bootstrap min js, so jquery, popper then bootstrap js https://jsfiddle.net/L7xgzsem/

Comment: You guys are right!, it is working now.